# ZF2 Doctrine2 repository result as array

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have the problem, that I have two controllers. One is a restful controller which only handles `json` data and returns a `JsonModel`, and the other one is a default controller which returns a `ViewModel` 
Now I have the problem, that my method only returns an `array` of entities, which is correct for the default controller, but my restful controller needs the entities as an array. How can I handle this?

**MealController**

```
class MealController extends AbstractRestfulController {
    protected $mealService;

    public function getList() {
        $meals = $this->mealService->getAllMeals();

        return new JsonModel($meals);
    }
}
```

**MealService**

```
class MealService {
    protected $mealRepository;

    public function getAllMeals() {
        return $this->mealRepository->findAll();
    }
}
```

**MealRepository**

```
class MealRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function findAll() {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('meal')
            ->orderBy('title');

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You coud use for that [Array Hydration](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/class-Doctrine.ORM.Internal.Hydration.ArrayHydrator.html). It allows to specify a hydration mode when executing queries, and change the data type of the results returned. You just need to use the constant `Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY` as parameter in your `getResult()` method :

```
public function findAll() {
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('meal')
        ->orderBy('title');

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

Maybe you could also take a look at the [EntitySerializer](https://github.com/borisguery/bgylibrary/blob/master/library/Bgy/Doctrine/EntitySerializer.php) class which let you create an array of json from an entity :

```
$entitySerializer = new EntitySerializer($em);
$entityAsArray = $entitySerializer->toArray($entity);
```

Comment: Array Hydration looks good, but that way, the method always returns an array. But it also feels weird to add a parameter $hydration in my service method "getAllMeals" and repository method "findAll", or would that be the correct way? 

So i would have:

`public function getAllMeals($hydration = Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT) ;
public function findAll($hydration = Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT) ;`

Comment: I don't know if there is a better way but yes you could eventualy do that, it's not so weired ;-)

Comment: Ok I'll do it that way! Thanks ;-)